# ¿Como usar CarbonPeriod en español?

Tags: php, laravel, web, date, carbon

Hola estoy tratando de hacer perdidos de fechas en español usando Carbón y CarbonPeriod en Laravel 10, el problema es que algunos métodos necesitan los meses en inglés por ejemplo el método de `CarbonPeriod::create()` si yo uso esto `CarbonPwriod::create('enero','1 month','diciembre')` este me da un error  que dice: `Could not parse 'enero': Failed to parse time string (enero) at position 0 (e): The timezone could not be found in the database` empece a investigar y resulta que se debe de cambiar el locale a español e hice esto:

```
 public function boot(): void
 {
    setlocale(LC_TIME,'es_MX');
    Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
    CarbonPeriod::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
 }
```

pero esto solo funciona para que me traiga los meses y dias en español y necesito que me pueda crear un periodo usando fechas en español aqui esta mi codigo

```
   private function getMounthOfYear()
   {
    $until = $this->yearSelected == Carbon::now()->year ? Carbon::now()->monthName //esto lo da en español : 'diciembre';
     //esto falla
    $period = CarbonPeriod::create('enero', '1 month', $until);
    return iterator_to_array($period->map(function ($date) {
        return ucwords($date->monthName // esto lo da en español);
    }));
   }
```

Comment: Porque pasar un string en lugar de una fecha?

Comment: @gbianchi necesito que el usuario elija solo el mes y año el cual quiere el reporte (ya que con esto se traerá todos los registros del mes y año de la base de datos)

Comment: claro.. pero eso, te va a dar una fecha en numero... no un mes en cadena ;)... estas equivocado y complicando todo por esa parte.. cuando el usuario selecciona enero (que supongo lo elige de un combo) vos recibis un 1... no enero ;)

Comment: @gbianchi me podrías dar algún ejemplo?

Comment: [`Carbon::parseFromLocale`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) -> `$date = Carbon::parseFromLocale('mercredi 6 mars 2019 + 3 jours', 'fr', 'UTC'); // timezone is optional`

Comment: @LuisGarcia algun ejemplo de que?